# Postgresql as OLTP and OLAP

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

We are having a postgresSQL database (9.5 version). We have 2 schema to segregate as following

1. Main transaction database
2. Data warehouse database

We want to maintain history of all transaction that's occurring in transaction database schema to be in datawarehouse database schema as well.

For ex: If we have employee address table getting updated in in transaction database schema from a User Interface, then the same update should happen in a similar address table in datawarehouse database schema.

We looked at trigger and materialised view option. But in trigger, if there is failure when the trigger executes for some reason(ex: constraint error), then until we fix that issue all the changes that are made in API will not casacade from transaction schema to datawarehouse schema.

Can you provide some direction on how to manage the data copies between tables in different schemas at realtime in postgresql.

Please let me know if I couldn't explain my requirement well

Comment: Well isn't the behaviour of the trigger expected and required? If your update on the OLTP database fails and the transaction is rolled back, why do you want to still apply that update to the DWH? That would mean the DWH database contained wrong information. If you upgrade to Postgres 10, you could do this with logical replication which is probably faster than a trigger - but that is also transactional (which is the only correct way to do it in my opinion)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Regarding your comments on update failure on oltp, actually I meant there is a failure on trigger when I update from oltp to olap. So in that case, oltp has data and olap wouldn't until I make a production release to fix the issue in trigger. Meanwhile oltp snapshot would have changed and updated with recent transaction and I wouldn't have a back up in oltp to push the same to olap once I have fixed the trigger, so we fear we might miss the transactions in oltp.